# Web Page to Generate an Email

Tags: joomla-3.4

Can someone let me know how to get clicking on a link to produce an email?

I've created a link for users that wish to unsubscribe to my email notifications. Can someone let me know how I can get the page to automatically send me an email (or notify me that the person wishes to unsubscribe) without the user having to actually send me an email?

I using joomla 3.4.5

Cheers

Carlton

Comment: Alternatively, can you show me how users can unsubscribe by clicking on a link?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of unnecessary ongoing work when you can use any number of inbuilt mailing plugins or external mailing services to not only automate your subscribes and unsubscribes, but also provide you with good looking templates out-of-the-box and also much better delivery rates (assuming you are using your email program to send mail out via your ISP). Also this would avoid email throttling on your ISP, and they have plugins for you fav CMS, or JS/HTML embed scripts.

Get a free Mailchimp account http://eepurl.com/WL8n5 or similar account from any number of mailing services.

Comment: Yeah, you should be sending to your mailing list using a proper newsletter. Acymailing Starter is fantastic.

Comment: Why not let MailChimp do all the work for you? mailchimp.com

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send yourself an email telling you that a user wishes to unsubscribe, you can simply make this your link:

```
<a href="mailto:example@example.com?subject=Unsubscribe me&body=I want to unsubscribe from your emails" target="_blank">Unsubscribe</a>
```

This will open a pre-populated email for the user. Once you received it, you can then manually go into the Joomla backend and delete their email from the mailing list.

If you want it done automatically, then you most likely want to use a plugin.

Hope this helps

Comment: Guys, can you advise on a simple mail plugin?

Comment: I have been checking out mailchimp but I can't see how it provides a mailing pluggin.

Comment: @cpatte7372 - Please check the Joomla Extensions Directory as there are loads to choose from.

Comment: If you don't want spammers to scrape your email address, don't use this method unless you have obfuscated the email. And frankly spam bots are now generally smart enough to parse most obfuscation methods so still don't use this method even with email obfuscation. In general, either use some form of contact form submission method where the email address is held in the backend only such as a contact form or mailout plugin, or use an external maillist management service like Mailchimp.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking on a link to send you an email I would suggest that **you avoid any mail setups that create more manual work for you**. To make something of your site you should automate as much as possible, and ensure you have the best delivery rates for all your email.

Nowadays in this spam-challenged world, unless you run your own server with dedicated IP address, you want to avoid handling mail from your web server or being sent direct ly by you through your local ISP's mail server. In doing so, you will avoid mail throttling, poor mail reputation from shared IP addresses, and buggy and inflexible mail solutions etc.

As such, inbuilt mailout plugins are IMHO not a very good solution anymore unless you are combining the with a external SMTP mail service like Sendgrid. I haven't used a mailout plugin for over 10 years as there are too many downsides and I get more flexiblity with Mailchimp and their API.

Mailchimp is a mail and templating service. http://eepurl.com/WL8n5
It is free for the first 2000 addresses and 12000 emails per month.
You integrate Mailchimp using a Joomla Mailchimp plugin, linking your chosen mailchimp list(s) to the site. Different Mailchimp plugins provide different levels of integration options. You can use them to place newsletter sign-up modules, or auto add to lists on member registration etc. just as you would with an ibuilt mailout plugin. And combined with a code plugin like Sourcerer (which allows you to easily place raw code anywhere you want on your Joomla site), I find that you can get much essentially almost limitless flexibility in customising your own sign-up forms and boxes.

And, as stated, ensure good delivery rates for your outbound web server system emails using a free Sendgrid account http://sendgrid.com.